# VS2013 performance

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Are there any tools which i can use to diagnose performance issues with VisualStudio 2013 Premium edition?

I'm currently running the Update2 RC (however speed has been the same prior also). and have a few extensions running

- Web Essentials for Update 2 RC
- Rename Visual Studio Window Title
- Productivity power tools
- nunit test adapter
- ReadyRoll.

On an Intel Xeon E3-1220 V2 3.10GHz, machine with 8G of RAM i frequently experience performance issues which seem out of character to the resource available to Visual Studio.

The example scenario is a webforms project in a solution which references 19 other library projects, which is controlled by an in house TFS2012. Browser link is disabled, and the solution is built and deployed against the local IIS rather than IISexpress etc.

- having two instances of visual studio open which have versions of the solution from different branches appears to have a large impact on performance.
- switching between two instances of Visual studio can often cause a hanging state for a minute.
- pasting code(even a small paragraph) ontop of code in an existing file (aspx,.vb) can cause a minute or so hang.

Answer (score 1):

You did check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff716700.aspx) page? it contains some tips from microsoft for troubleshooting performance.
You could also use i.e. process monitor from sysinternals to check what VS is actually doing in regards to file and registry access.

Another tip could be to delete this C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\